# How can I replace a lambda function which is part of a CfnInclude imported stack?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I'm importing a Cloudformation template into CDK using like this:

```
const template = new include.CfnInclude(this, "Include", {
  templateFile: "../cloudformation-template/serverless.template.generated",
  parameters: {}
});
```

The imported CloudFormation template includes an API Gateway REST API resource which references S3 hosted swagger files. Each of the swagger files define a set of API methods. Each API method references an authorizer:

```
"securityDefinitions": {
    "MyCustomAuthorizer": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "name": "Authorization",
      "in": "header",
      "x-amazon-apigateway-authtype": "custom",
      "x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer": {
        "authorizerUri": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "arn:aws:apigateway:",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
              },
              ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/",
              {
                "Fn::GetAtt": ["MyCustomAuthorizerLambda", "Arn"]
              },
              "/invocations"
            ]
          ]
        },
        "authorizerResultTtlInSeconds": 300,
        "identitySource": "method.request.header.Authorization, context.path, context.httpMethod",
        "type": "request"
      }
    }
  },
```

The swagger methods are defined like this:

```
"/MyGETMethod.json": {
  "get": {
    "security": [{
      "MyCustomAuthorizer": []
    }],
    ....
  }
}
```

Going forward I want to maintain this stack using CDK. I'm trying to replace the imported lambda function with a new one which I've created in CDK:

```
var myNewAuthorizerLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'MyNewAuthorizerLambda', {
  runtime: ...
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(...),
  description: `An API Gateway Authorizer.`,
  handler: ...
```

The lambda replacement needs to ensure any API method which referenced the old lambda is changed to reference the new CDK one instead. I've attempted a number of approaches, such as the 'replaceDependency' method and iterating through the nodes, but I can't work it out. Can someone point me in the right direction? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. It's actually pretty simple:

```
// Remove the 'old' lambda
template.node.tryRemoveChild('MyCustomAuthorizerLambda');

// Define the new function
var myNewAuthorizerLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'MyCustomAuthorizerLambda', {
  runtime: ...
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(...),
  description: `An API Gateway Authorizer.`,
  handler: ...
}

// Ensure the 'new' lambda has the same logical ID as the old one
const cfnMyNewAuthorizerLambda  = myNewAuthorizerLambda.node.defaultChild as lambda.CfnFunction;
cfnMyNewAuthorizerLambda.overrideLogicalId('MyCustomAuthorizerLambda');
```

I'm not sure why the overrideLogicalId bit is necessary - I'd have expected that reusing the id in the definition of the new lambda.Function would have been enough, but it appears not.